# Custom Beamer theme with horizontal sections and subsections at the top?

Tags: beamer

This might look silly. I don't know how to customize or find the Beamer theme I need.

What I need is similar to the below theme, but having *all* sections and related subsections oriented horizontally in the upper bar (not vertically like the below). However, I want the lower bar to be the same as the below theme.

I really appreciate any tips on how to do this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK I think the key is to use "compress":

```
\documentclass[compress,8pt]{beamer}
\useoutertheme{split}
```